# Getting index element of statically built std::array at compile time (attempt to access run-time storage error)

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to get the index of element by it's name at compile time however function result doesn't get evaluated at compile time.

I build a test project where I build a `static` `std::array` with predefined elements which contain const char* and string.
Then I wrote a `constexpr` function which takes array and `const* char` as parameters, compares `const char*` with `const* char` of elements in the array and returns it's index.
I added `std::is_constant_evaluated()` check to see if the function was evaluated at compile time. It wasn't.

Code is attached below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct myStruct {
    const char* Name = NULL;
    std::string Value{};
    myStruct(const char* IniName, std::string Value) : Name{}, Value{} {};
};

std::array<myStruct, 2>  ar_Structs = {
     myStruct("Name1", "Value1"),
    myStruct("Name2", "Value2")
};


template <class X>
constexpr int findIndexOf(X ar, const char* NameToSearchFor) {

    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {

    }
    else {
        static_assert(false, "Not evaluated at compile time");
    }

    size_t i = 0;
    return 1;
    while (i < ar.size()) {
        if (strcmp(NameToSearchFor, ar[i].IniName) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }

        ++i;
    }


    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr auto Pos1 = findIndexOf(ar_Structs, "Name1");
}
```

Comment: `ar_Structs` is not a `constexpr` variable, and `strcmp` is not a `constexpr` function. How do you expect your function to be calculated at compile time?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `static_assert` to test this. It is "evaluated" at the time of the instantiation/definition where it occurs. It won't consider the context in which the function is called or control flow of the `if` statement.

If the evaluation was not happening at compile-time then `constexpr auto Pos1 = findIndexOf(ar_Structs, "Name1");` would fail to compile, because a `constexpr` variable requires the initialization to be a constant expression. There is no other way to verify that an evaluation happens at compile-time during compilation.

(Technically nothing is ever guaranteed to be evaluated at compile-time, but a context where a constant expression is mandatory has this as intended implementation effect.)

And the compiler should be complaining (after removal of the `static_assert`) that the initialization is not a constant expression, already because `ar_Structs` isn't usable in constant expressions. It can't possibly be usable in constant expressions, because nothing prevents its value to be changed at runtime. However, even if you add some `constexpr` you can't make it `constexpr` because it contains `std::string`'s which aren't guaranteed to be able to be stored as (part of) `constexpr` variables (and certainly won't as soon as the string contents become larger enough).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for detailed answer.  I agree that std:Array can be changed during runtime but the point of my code was to get element by it's name which is not a subject to change. Value hovewer needs to be changed.Does what you say mean that my task is impossible to be done?

Comment: @NormakLOE32 You declared `findIndexOf` to take its argument by-copy. So this already requires copying of the actual values stored in the array.  And when you remove the `return 1;` and assuming that `IniName` is a typo for `Name`, then it still fails to be a constant expression if you take the argument by-reference, because `Name` is not fixed at compile-time. It isn't really possible to make a variable partially usable at compile-time.